# c++　行列の乗算　警告がでる

Tags: c++, 行列

何がいけないのでしょうか

**コード**

```cpp
vector<double> MatrixVector(vector<vector<double>> A,
    vector<double> b){
    unsigned long   m=A.size();
    unsigned long   n=A.front().size();
    vector<vector<double>> d(m);

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            d[i][j]=0;

            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                d[i][j] += A[i][k] * b[j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**警告メッセージ**

> control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: エラーの内容を提示してください。

Comment: errorを本文に追加しました

Comment: ありがとうございます。return d[m]とすると解決できました

Comment: 回答によって問題が解決した場合には、該当の回答を「承認」してあげてください。 - 参考ヘルプ: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

警告の通りです。`MatrixVector`関数には`vector<double>`型の戻り値が存在すると宣言されていますが、`return`文が書かれていません。